# Flutter: Server side apple sign in error ( client_id mismatch )

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-sign-in, apple-oauth2

We have a website with Apple login. The App ID and service ID for this login are `com.website.login` and `com.website.service.login` respectively and users are able to log in without any issues.

Now, we are building a mobile app and would like to authenticate the user on the server. To do this, I am using `sign_in_with_apple` package ([link](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple)). We are using the same clientId that we are using over our website - `com.website.service.login`. Here's a code snippet of the same:

```
 credentials = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: scopes,
      webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
        clientId: 'com.website.service.login',   
        redirectUri: Uri.parse('https://website.com/apple/callback'),
      ),
      state: state,
    );
```

When I verify the code using the post request to my callback, I get the error -
`client_id mismatch. The code was not issued to com.website.service.login`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe not exact answer, but in my case it helped to change `serviceId` to the app `bundleId` on server side for iOS application.

The example below, which is included in the sign_in_with_apple package, is also showing that part (in my case, I completely missed it).

```js
app.post("/sign_in_with_apple", async (request, response) => {
  const auth = new AppleAuth(
    {
      // use the bundle ID as client ID for native apps, else use the service ID for web-auth flows
      // https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118135
      client_id:
        request.query.useBundleId === "true"
          ? process.env.BUNDLE_ID
          : process.env.SERVICE_ID,
      team_id: process.env.TEAM_ID,
      redirect_uri:
        "https://flutter-sign-in-with-apple-example.glitch.me/callbacks/sign_in_with_apple", // does not matter here, as this is already the callback that verifies the token after the redirection
      key_id: process.env.KEY_ID
    },
    process.env.KEY_CONTENTS.replace(/\|/g, "\n"),
    "text"
  );
}
```

Source:
[https://glitch.com/~flutter-sign-in-with-apple-example](https://glitch.com/%7Eflutter-sign-in-with-apple-example)

Answer (score 0):

When packaging using automatic mode in Xcode, no errors are reported. However, after signing the package Sign in with Apple, logging into the Apple server returns the following error:
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"client_id mismatch. The code was not issued to xxx.xxx.xxx."}

When manually packaging and importing profile in Xcode, an error will be prompted.
Provisioning profile "xxxx" has app ID "xxx.xxx1.xxx", which does not match the bundle ID "xxx.xxx2.xxx".

The reason for the error is that the bundle ID manually entered for the first time is different from the bundle ID configured in the app store. You can double check and verification it again. And after modified it，the bug is fixed.